# Find first line of text according to value in Python

Tags: python, search, text, filter, find

How can I do a search of a value of the first "latitude, longitude" coordinate in a "file.txt" list in Python and get 3 rows above and 3 rows below?

### Value

```
37.0459
```

### file.txt

```
37.04278,-95.58895
37.04369,-95.58592
37.04369,-95.58582
37.04376,-95.58557
37.04376,-95.58546
37.04415,-95.58429
37.0443,-95.5839
37.04446,-95.58346
37.04461,-95.58305
37.04502,-95.58204
37.04516,-95.58184
37.04572,-95.58139
37.04597,-95.58127
37.04565,-95.58073
37.04546,-95.58033
37.04516,-95.57948
37.04508,-95.57914
37.04494,-95.57842
37.04483,-95.5771
37.0448,-95.57674
37.04474,-95.57606
37.04467,-95.57534
37.04462,-95.57474
37.04458,-95.57396
37.04454,-95.57274
37.04452,-95.57233
37.04453,-95.5722
37.0445,-95.57164
37.04448,-95.57122
37.04444,-95.57054
37.04432,-95.56845
37.04432,-95.56834
37.04424,-95.5668
37.044,-95.56251
37.04396,-95.5618
```

### Expected Result

```
37.04502,-95.58204
37.04516,-95.58184
37.04572,-95.58139
37.04597,-95.58127
37.04565,-95.58073
37.04546,-95.58033
37.04516,-95.57948
```

### Additional information

In linux I can get the closest line and do the treatment I need using grep, sed, cut and others, but I'd like in Python.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do a search of a value of the first "latitude, longitude"
>   coordinate in a "file.txt" list in Python and get 3 rows above and 3
>   rows below?*

---

You can try:

```
with open("text_filter.txt") as f:
    text = f.readlines() # read text lines to list

    filter= "37.0459"
    match = [i for i,x in enumerate(text) if filter in x] # get list index of item matching filter
    if match:
        if len(text) >= match[0]+3: # if list has 3 items after filter, print it
            print("".join(text[match[0]:match[0]+3]).strip())
        print(text[match[0]].strip())
        if match[0] >= 3:  # if list has 3 items before filter, print it
            print("".join(text[match[0]-3:match[0]]).strip())
```

---

**Output:**

```
37.04597,-95.58127
37.04565,-95.58073
37.04546,-95.58033
37.04597,-95.58127
37.04502,-95.58204
37.04516,-95.58184
37.04572,-95.58139
```

Comment: There are some problems with this solution: 1/ looking for "37.044" matches the line "37.04415,-95.58429" 2/ It returns wrong results if the match is in the last 3 lines of the file.

Comment: Sometimes what users ask isn't exactly what they need. OP seem satisfied with result and I'm ok with that.Thank you for  pointing that anyways. GL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to import the data in a dataframe and then easily manipulate it. As per your question the value to check is not the exact match and therefore I have converted it to string.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("file.txt", header=None, names=["latitude","longitude"]) #imports text file as dataframe
value_to_check = 37.0459 # user defined
for i in range(len(data)):
    if str(value_to_check) == str(data.iloc[i,0])[:len(str(value_to_check))]:
        break
print(data.iloc[i-3:i+4,:])
```

**output**

```
    latitude  longitude
9   37.04502  -95.58204
10  37.04516  -95.58184
11  37.04572  -95.58139
12  37.04597  -95.58127
13  37.04565  -95.58073
14  37.04546  -95.58033
15  37.04516  -95.57948
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with iterators, that only keeps in memory the necessary lines and doesn't load the unnecessary part of the file:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice


def find_in_file(file, target, before=3, after=3):

    queue = deque(maxlen=before)
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if target in map(float, line.split(',')):
                out = list(queue) + [line] + list(islice(f, 3))
                return out
            queue.append(line)
        else:
            raise ValueError('target not found')
```

Some tests:

```
print(find_in_file('test.txt', 37.04597))

# ['37.04502,-95.58204\n', '37.04516,-95.58184\n', '37.04572,-95.58139\n', '37.04597,-95.58127\n',
#  '37.04565,-95.58073\n', '37.04565,-95.58073\n', '37.04565,-95.58073\n']

print(find_in_file('test.txt', 37.044))  # Only one line after the match

# ['37.04432,-95.56845\n', '37.04432,-95.56834\n', '37.04424,-95.5668\n', '37.044,-95.56251\n', 
#   '37.04396,-95.5618\n']
```

Also, it works if there is less than the expected number of lines before or after the match. We match floats, not strings, as '37.04' would erroneously match '37.0444' otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will print the before and after elements even if they are less than 3.
Also I am using string as it is implied from the question that you want partial matches also. **ie. 37.0459 will match  37.04597**

```
search_term='37.04462'
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in lines] #remove '\n'
for lat,lon in lines:
    if search_term in lat:
        index=lines.index([lat,lon])
        break
left=0
right=0
for k in range (1,4): #bcoz last one is not included
    if index-k >=0:
        left+=1
    if index+k<=(len(lines)-1):
        right+=1
for i in range(index-left,index+right+1): #bcoz last one is not included
    print(lines[i][0],lines[i][1])
```